# how to get image url attribute in django

Tags: django, imageurl

i have a problem with getting image url in django template.
In views file i am getting "product__stock_keeping_unit__image" which is related products' image as below.

`data = models.Product.objects.filter(category__slug=slug, product__is_default=True).values("id", "name", "product__sku", "slug", "category__name", "product__store_price", "product__sub_product__units", "product__stock_keeping_unit__image")`

in template file i am trying to display image

```
{% for item in data %}
        <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4 text-center">
            <div class="product-entry border">
                <a href="#" class="prod-img">
                    <img src="{{ item.product__stock_keeping_unit__image.url }}">
                </a>
                <div class="desc">
                    <h2><a href="{% url 'product_detail' item.slug item.product__sku %}">{{ item.name }}</a></h2>
                    <span class="price">${{ item.product__store_price }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       {% endfor %}
```

Everything works fine except **img** field.
**In the page source i am getting empty string. But when i write** `<img src="{{ item.product__stock_keeping_unit__image }}">` **i am getting image path in page source `images/men-shoes.jpg` but not add MEDIA_URL `/media/images/men-shoes.jpg` into path.**

Settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

How can i solve this problem. Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the media prefix like so:

```
src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ item.product__stock_keeping_unit__image }}">
```

and set some url settings for development mode like so:

```
# urls.py

..
urlpatterns = [
   ...
]

# Serving the media files in development mode
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
else:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Answer (score 0):

`.values(...)` returns queryset containing dictionary, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#values). Therefore you will not able to access url property of image field.

Use standard django object that exposes property of the image field. You can use following:

Query:

`data = models.Product.objects.filter(category__slug=slug, product__is_default=True)`

In template

`<img src="{{ item.product.tock_keeping_unit.image.url }}">`

p.s. you can use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for performance

Comment: The problem is that my Product table does not store any foreign key. Instead my SubProduct table store product_id so, i can't access item.product.stock_keeping_unit.image.url.